# Django Custom Template for GenericSitemap

Tags: django, sitemap, urlconf

I have a generic sitemap working. I'm now looking to customize the output.

Im passing in the custom template_name but it doesn't use it

```
(r'^sitemap/$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
{'sitemaps':sitemaps, 'template_name':'sitemap.xml'}),
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with that. Are you sure your updated `urls.py` is being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason changing sitemap.xml to sitemap.html worked